# Use shared library created with Matlab Compiler SDK in OMNeT++ simulation

Tags: omnet++, matlab-compiler

I am trying to call Matlab Functions from my OMNeT simulation. Therefore I created a shared library using the mwArray API. However, when I try to run the sample code, the simulation terminates with the following error message:

Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

Did anyone else encounter the same problem?

I am using OMNeT 5.6.2 and Matlab 2020a under Windows

The code for my module is

```
    #include <omnetpp.h>
    #include "compilerTest.h"
    
    using namespace omnetpp;
    
    class ExampleModule : public cSimpleModule
    {
        protected:
            simtime_t timerInterval;
            cMessage * timer;
        protected:
            virtual void initialize();
            virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
    };
    
    Define_Module(ExampleModule);
    
    void ExampleModule::initialize()
    {
        timerInterval = 1.0;
        timer = new cMessage("timer");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + timerInterval, timer);
    }
    
    void ExampleModule::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
    {
        if (msg->isSelfMessage()){
                bool x = mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0);
    
                scheduleAt(simTime() + timerInterval, timer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the error occurred during the startup of the process. It means that the process probably cannot load the Matlab runtime DLL. The directories where the Matlab DLLs reside must be present on the system path so the operating system can load them. On Windows it is especially hard to avoid DLL hell and fix these issues (mostly because of the lack of proper error messages). First, I would try to start the example from the MinGW env command prompt where you can control the PATH manually and try to run from the IDE only after it works in the command line.